# Sharing of a view among microservies

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I'm splitting up a monolith web service into several microservices using spring boot. To reduce duplicated code I extracted shared parts in a maven module that is used in the different microservices.

The monolith application had a healthcheck page that showed various information about the state of the service and some debbuging infos. It is implemented with Spring MVC and jsp.

I'd like to use this view in each of the microservices. Whats the best way to do this without duplicating the view/controller?

I was thinking of adding a web module to the shared maven project that contains the controller, view, spring mvc settings,...
But I'm not sure if it is good to have two web modules in one microservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using spring boot actuator to retrieve health (and more) application information?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready

You could then have another microservice that retrieves that information from each of your services, or just simply check it on then hitting the different endpoints (/health, /env, etc.).

**UPDATE:**

If you have you custom health logic you can even implement your own actuator endpoint for it. Furthermore, you can create your own library to reuse it in all your microservices:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-endpoints-programmatically

> **46.4 Adding custom endpoints**
>
> If you add a @Bean of type Endpoint then it will automatically be exposed over JMX and HTTP (if there is an
> server available). An HTTP endpoints can be customized further by
> creating a bean of type MvcEndpoint. Your MvcEndpoint is not a
> @Controller but it can use @RequestMapping (and @Managed*) to expose
> resources.
>
> **[Tip]**
> If you are doing this as a library feature consider adding a
> configuration class annotated with @ManagementContextConfiguration to
> /META-INF/spring.factories under the key
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementContextConfiguration.
> If you do that then the endpoint will move to a child context with all
> the other MVC endpoints if your users ask for a separate management
> port or address. A configuration declared this way can be a
> WebConfigurerAdapter if it wants to add static resources (for
> instance) to the management endpoints.

Comment: thank you for your idea. the thing is, that this page provides more than just health information. You can change the log loglevels of that service and start/stop some tasks that run on that service. It is very customized and the goal is to save time and for now just reuse the existing solution for each microservice.

Comment: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin does all that and when you use a service discovery mechanism you just need to deploy a single instance and it will detect them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I need some time to dig into this.